ようになる with non-potential verbs
All the grammar explanations of ようになる that I've seen say that this phrase is used with the potential form of verbs. I couldn't even find an example sentence without a potential verb. Recently, however, I stumbled upon two sentences where the dictionary form of a verb is used (I am only pasting the most relevant part of each sentence):



おかしなことが起こるようになった




黒い影を、何度も見かけるようになった



My understanding of ようになる in (1) is that of "weird things started to happen (previously they didn't happen)". But applying the same principle to (2) results in "I started noticing a black shade many times (previously I haven't noticed any black shade)", which is kind of silly. To me, (1) sounds natural because it describes a state of things, but not noticing a black shade is hardly a state, at least from my perspective. I don't know... Am I overthinking this, and you can use ようになる with any kind of transition from "something is not true" to "something is true"?

I think your English translation might be tripping you up. Perhaps it sounds more natural with "frequently" rather than "many times". As in, some time ago the black shade was not noticed, but nowadays the speaker commonly notices it.

The sentence "黒い影を、何度も見かけるようになった" is perfectly natural in Japanese. In this case, "ようになった" refers the fact that something is occurring more frequently than before. So, the sentence means:
"I've started seeing a black shadow more frequently than before."
Additionally, it is important to note that "ようになる" does not always imply that something has never happened before. Sometimes it simply means that something has started to happen more frequently or more noticeably. For example:

頭痛がするようになった -- I've started getting headaches more frequently."

This does not necessarily mean the speaker never had headaches before, but that they occurred much less frequently in the past.
Similarly, "黒い影を、何度も見かけるようになった" does not necessarily mean the speaker never had seen the black shadow before, but the speaker had much less frequently in the past.
